# MATLAB - How should I choose the FunctionTolerance of genetic algorithm optimisation?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am optimising MRI experiment settings in order to get optimal precision of tissue property measurements using my data.

To optimise the settings (i.e. a vector of numbers) I am using the MATLAB genetic algorithm function (ga()). I want to compare the final result of different optimisation experiments, that have different parameter upper bounds but I do not know how to choose the *FunctionTolerance*.

My current implementation takes several days. I would like to increase *FunctionTolerance* so that it does not take as long, yet still allows me to make reliable comparisons of the final results of the two different optimisation experiments. In other words, I do not want to stop the optimisation too early. I want to stop it when it gets close to its best results, but not wait for a long time for it to refine the result.

Is there a general rule for choosing *FunctionTolerance* or does it depend on what is being optimised?

Comment: What's your cost function?

Comment: My cost function is based on the measurement precision. 


Firstly the cost function simulates data (signal time courses) for the given MRI experiment settings, using a Monte Carlo approach with 1000 different noise seeds. Fitting is performed on these 1000 time course. This gives a distribution of 1000 measurement errors. My cost function value is the measurement efficiency =  true value /  ( (measurement error standard deviation)*sqrt( length of simulated MRI experiment) )

Comment: The tissue property, the measurement errors and the length of the simulated MRI experiment are all in units of seconds.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any good ideas. Perhaps another site on stackexchange is better suited?